# applying style to every button on form

Tags: c#, winforms, button, styles

I have the following method which works fine:

```
button21.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
button21.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
```

As you can see, I have many buttons (~30), so instead of applying style on every button - why not apply on all of them at once on `Form_Load` event? So I wrote this method:

```
public void ChangeButtonStyles()
{
    foreach (Control con in this.Controls)
    {
        if (con is Button)
        {
            Button but = con as Button;
            but.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            but.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        }
    }
}
```

But it's not working because when you hover a mouse on a button -  you can see background change, which proves that `but.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;` is not working

Why isn't the code working?

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

  // works
    //button21.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
    //button21.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;

  // doesn't work
    ChangeButtonStyles();
}
```

**EDIT: Solution**

```
public void ChangeButtonStyles()
{
    foreach (Control con in this.Controls)
    {
        if (con is Button)
        {
            Button but = con as Button;
            but.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            but.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        }
        if (con is GroupBox)
        {
            foreach (Control subcon in con.Controls)
            {
                if (subcon is Button)
                {
                    Button but = subcon as Button;
                    but.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
                    but.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Iterating the controls is one way to do it. If you have a special formatting you want to apply to all buttons, why not implement your own button control?

Comment: Your solution will fall over as soon as you have a button nested three levels. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried debugging the code to see if it actually gets executed? this.Controls will return the top level controls. If the buttons are nested inside other controls you need to be more recursive.

```
public void ChangeButtonStyles(Control source)
{
    foreach (Control con in source.Controls)
    {
        if (con is Button)
        {
            Button but = con as Button;
            but.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            but.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        }
        else
        {
            ChangeButtonStyles(con);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, after giving it further thought - your solution is better than mine. answer accepted ;)